# Specifying colours when using matplotlib's pcolormesh

Tags: python, matplotlib

Using matplotlib, I want to be able to specify exact colors with pcolormesh. Here is what I have tried

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
```

imports at the top

```
X = np.linspace(0,1,100)
Y = np.linspace(0,1,100)
X,Y = np.meshgrid(X,Y)
Z = (X**2 + Y**2) < 1.
Z = Z.astype(int)
Z += (X**2 + Y**2) < .5
```

set up a bunch of fake data. `Z` is only `0`s, `1`s, and `2`s (this is like my real problem).

```
plt.pcolormesh(X,Y,Z,color=[(1,1,0),(0,0,1),(1,0,1)])
```

call `pcolormesh` with a `color` argument in a vain attempt to get a yellow, blue, and magenta plot. In fact, I got the default colors!

[image: pcolormesh]

My question is: how do I call `pcolormesh` to get the first area to be yellow, the second blue, and the third magenta?

Comment: I think you need to specify a colormap that contains these colors. I.e.
``plt.pcolormesh(X,Y,Z, cmap=plt.cm.Spectral)``

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One way is to use a custom colormap:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import colors as c

X = np.linspace(0,1,100)
Y = np.linspace(0,1,100)
X,Y = np.meshgrid(X,Y)
Z = (X**2 + Y**2) < 1.
Z = Z.astype(int)
Z += (X**2 + Y**2) < .5

cMap = c.ListedColormap(['y','b','m'])

plt.pcolormesh(X,Y,Z,cmap=cMap)
plt.show()
```

[image: plot showing custom color map with yellow, blue, magenta]

Comment: Thanks. I had thought about a colormap, but I didn't know about matplotlib.colors.ListedColormap. So, I thought it would be very awkward.